# Two controllers, one scope variable in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Okay so I have two controllers that control two distinctly different parts of the site, that are on the same page.

The first is for a newsletter signup form, the second is for a basket. The second is not directly placed in the DOM as an `ng-controller` directive, but instead as a controller for a custom directive.

Some code:

```
<div ng-controller="newsletter-signup">
    <div ng-show="showLoader">
        ... Cool loading animation here ...
    </div>

    ... Form in here ...
</div>

<div basket>
    <div ng-show="showLoader">
        ... Cool loading animation here ...
    </div>

    ... Basket data in here ...
</div>
```

The problem that I am having is that both of these contain a `div` that I only want to show under certain conditions, and this div is stored in a template file:

```
<div ng-show="showLoader">
    ... Cool loading animation here ...
</div>
```

This however get's shown on both the newsletter and basket when `$scope.showLoader` is `true` in either of the controllers.

I can't seem to figure out how to isolate the scopes from each other, but continue to use the same variable name.

The basket directive looks like this:

```
return {
    link : linkFn,
    scope: '=',
    restrict : 'A',
    controller : 'BasketController'
};
```

`BasketController` is never defined in the template.

How can I get to a resolution with this?

I don't want the `div` for the newsletter to show when the basket is being updated, and likewise, I don't want the `div` for the basket to show when the newsletter is being updated.

EDIT: We are using the following to define components, I am wondering if this is the root cause.

```
window.angular.module('Basket', []);
window.angular.module('App', ['Basket']);
```

Comment: In a directive, you would use `scope: {}` to create an isolated scope. But does the basket directive have a template?  I just don't understand what it does based on what you posted.

Comment: The basket is an attribute attached to the wrapping `div` of some dynamic content. It doesn't have it's own template. I'll update to be clearer.

Comment: Do both divs have a common parent, whose scope might also contain a "showLoader" variable?

Comment: @SebastianS the `div`s parent won't ever contain the `showLoader`, and it also doesn't have it's own scope. I am trying to isolate the two from each other.

Comment: @AlexMcCabe Non-nested controllers _are_ isolated by default, so the question is: What happens on ancestor elements.

Comment: @SebastianS this _is_ what I thought, and it's causing us some issues, obviously. There are elements outside of the `basket` div that have access to it's scope vars, even though it shouldn't. There's one controller and one directive defined on the page, and they are not nested.

Comment: @SebastianS Please see edits to see if this could be part of the problem?

Comment: Based on the code snippets from your question I created this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gnkvrmor/1/ Both `showLoader` variables are isolated. I still think there is a nesting issue. Edit: Ok wasted my time. Sten did the same thing in his answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted by @jme11 you need to pass the scope key an object in order to get an isolated scope.

In both places the variable is different, the first place it's defined hence can be true or false. However the second place with the isolated scope unless we directly pass it the variable it will remained undefined and that is a falsy value in JS, hence the ng-show will not pass.

Here is a pen to illustrate the problem better...

```
return {
    link : linkFn,
    scope: {
      showLoader: '='
    },
    restrict : 'A',
    controller : 'BasketController'
};
```

http://codepen.io/stenmuchow/pen/BNrLZm?editors=101

Comment: Thank you for the help but I am still having some issues with it. The isolated scopes have caused me the most trouble out of everything I have tried with Angular so far. I have forked your pen and changed a couple things to be closer to what I am using it for, however I can't figure it: http://codepen.io/alexmccabe/pen/BNrLrY

Comment: Please see edits to see if this could be part of the problem?

Comment: Super close, but isolated scope applies to functions as well and variables! Whoops i accidentally overwrote the pen... But anyways, forget the isolated scope cuz its not needed and just makes for more confusion. http://codepen.io/stenmuchow/pen/KpogJJ

Comment: Unfortunately this is what I had before. I have discovered the root cause of the problem, I believe anyway. We are defining individual modules then calling them as dependencies to the `app` module, meaning that everything is in the global scope. We can't re-write the app at this stage, so I will have to find another route. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem I can show the isolated scope example I accidentally erased if it helps!

Comment: Also there are much better ways to define the modules than using the window object...

Comment: Yeah, if I could see that isolated scope version using the clicking to update scope variable, that would be fantastic. We are going to have to spend some time refactoring a large amount of code, but we are close to launch so at the moment we don't have the time.

Comment: http://codepen.io/stenmuchow/pen/mJxOVx - I am a freelance JS dev, so if you guys need any help just contact me!

Comment: You're an absolute legend is what you are. You've helped me understand how forced isolated scopes work. Thank you very much for your help :) you have been marked as correct.